Blender 4.1 how to correctly use "#Frame"?
How to correctly use #Frame to rotate camera around object?

Parent camera to empty.
select Empty.
Rotation Z: #Frame/30

Syntax tried: Rotation Z: #Frame/30 #frame/30
example tutorial

Works fine here. Are you sure you're using the Z rotation of the Empty rather than the Camera? You also need to start the animation of course (Ctrl-Space)!


The variable frame should be all lowercase.
Preceded with # to generate the driver with the simple expression frame/30. If you already wrote the expression, the driver with the expression is already made, as shown by the purple color of your input, so you shouldn't include the # again when you edit it. In fact, if you click the driven value, you should see the expression written already, but without #.

So in your case, when you first create the driver: #frame/30
If the driver already exists: frame/30.

